# The phone number field contains U.S. phone numbers, and needs to be modified to the international format, with "+1-" in front of the phone number

Tags: python, regex

I am using

```
import re
def transform_record(record):
  new_record = re.sub(r'(,[^a-zA-z])', r'\1+1-',record)
  return new_record

print(transform_record("Sabrina Green,802-867-5309,System Administrator")) 
#Excpected Output:::" Sabrina Green,+1-802-867-5309,System Administrator"
```

But I am getting output::

```
Sabrina Green,8+1-02-867-5309,S+-ystem Administrator
```

Comment: You may use `re.sub(r',(?=\d)', r',+1-',record)` to add `+1-` before a `,` that is followed with a digit.

Comment: Typo in the regular expression and the replacement is in wrong order. And generally: you are making the assumption the no other field ever starts with something else then a-z.

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

def transform_record(record):

new_record = re.sub(r',(?=\d)', r',+1-',record)

return new_record

print(transform_record("Sabrina Green,802-867-5309,System Administrator")) 
# Sabrina Green,+1-802-867-5309,System Administrator

print(transform_record("Eli Jones,684-3481127,IT specialist")) 
# Eli Jones,+1-684-3481127,IT specialist

print(transform_record("Melody Daniels,846-687-7436,Programmer")) 
# Melody Daniels,+1-846-687-7436,Programmer

print(transform_record("Charlie Rivera,698-746-3357,Web Developer")) 
# Charlie Rivera,+1-698-746-3357,Web Developer
```

Answer (score 3):

Below one is working.

```py
re.sub(r",([\d-]+)",r",+1-\1" ,record)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
>   “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.

```
def transform_record(record, number_field=1):
    fields = record.split(",")  # See note.
    if not fields[number_field].startswith("+1-"):
        fields[number_field] = "+1-" + fields[number_field]
    return ",".join(fields)
```

I have a note in the above implementation. You are probably working with CSV data. You should use a proper CSV parser instead of just splitting on commas if so. Just splitting on commas goes wrong if a field contains escaped commas.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is not well ordered, and you want to add `+1-` before any `,` that is followed with a digit, yo may use

```
re.sub(r',(?=\d)', r',+1-', record)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5pzMJT/1).

The `,(?=\d)` pattern matches a comma first, and then `(?=\d)` positive lookahead makes sure there is a digit right after, without consuming the digit (and it remains in the replacement result).

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/aVNlqm).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, detect the pattern from the record text by `r",(?=[0-9])"`. That means if there are some digits after `,` comma, then add `+1-` after the comma and then the previous phone number.

For example : `345-345-34567` convert to `+1-345-345-34567`

```
import re
def transform_record(record):
    new_record = re.sub(r",(?=[0-9])",",+1-",record)
    return new_record

print(transform_record("Sabrina Green,802-867-5309,System Administrator"))
# Sabrina Green,+1-802-867-5309,System Administrator

print(transform_record("Eli Jones,684-3481127,IT specialist")) 
# Eli Jones,+1-684-3481127,IT specialist

print(transform_record("Melody Daniels,846-687-7436,Programmer")) 
# Melody Daniels,+1-846-687-7436,Programmer

print(transform_record("Charlie Rivera,698-746-3357,Web Developer")) 
# Charlie Rivera,+1-698-746-3357,Web Developer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def transform_record(record):
    new_record = re.sub(r"([\d-]+)",r"+1-\1",record)
    return new_record
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_record = re.sub(r",([\d])",r",+1-",record)
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In this code we want to search one or more digit so you need to use \d in a class with the "+" sign and for re.sub you need to add the previous phone number with "+1"

---

```
new_record = re.sub(r',([\d]+)',r',+1\1', record)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

We can use parentheses to create a capture group in regex. Our first parameter **r"([0-9-]+)"**, holds  the pattern that will match one or more digits and - dashes in our variable record.
The second parameters **"+1-"r"\1"** will replace the matching string **”\1”** (backslash 1 represents first and the only capture group matched , this is [Backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) practice in regex) and we then add in the front of the capture string or phone number , the international format string **"+1-"** .

```py
import re

def transform_record(record):
  new_record = re.sub(r"([0-9-]+)", "+1-"r"\1", record)
  return new_record

print(transform_record("Sabrina Green,802-867-5309,System Administrator")) 
# Sabrina Green,+1-802-867-5309,System Administrator

print(transform_record("Eli Jones,684-3481127,IT specialist")) 
# Eli Jones,+1-684-3481127,IT specialist

print(transform_record("Melody Daniels,846-687-7436,Programmer")) 
# Melody Daniels,+1-846-687-7436,Programmer

print(transform_record("Charlie Rivera,698-746-3357,Web Developer")) 
# Charlie Rivera,+1-698-746-3357,Web Developer
```